# SQL Cursor Fetch Data without knowing Table Description

Tags: sql, cursor

I am writing a **`Pro* C`** function which would accept the table name and return the values stored in it.

```
select * from <table_name>
```

Now what we know from the basic programming of cursor is:

```
DECLARE 
emp_rec emp_tbl%rowtype;
CURSOR emp_cur IS 
SELECT *
FROM 
WHERE salary > 10; 
 BEGIN 
    OPEN emp_cur; 
    FETCH emp_cur INTO emp_rec; 
     dbms_output.put_line (emp_rec.first_name || '  ' || emp_rec.last_name); 
   CLOSE emp_cur; 
END;
```

here in the above code we need the `table description` so that we can use statements like

```
emp_rec.first_name
emp_rec.last_name
```

Suppose if we don't know about the description of table then how can we get the values from the cursor.

Is it possible.?

Comment: Can you explain better what it is that you want?. From the "`SELECT` from any table without knowing the table description" it looks like you want a `SELECT *`, but I'm guessing that that's not what you want

Comment: Dynamic SQL could handle it (it's a select on the sys tables to get the column names, load them into a cursor and loop through it to build your sql.  yes, thats a cursor to build a cursor).   Dynamic SQL opens some security issues, and to be honest my first reaction here is find a set based solution and don't use cursors.

Comment: @Twelfth: Sir, can you please elaborate... I din't get you.

Comment: Hmm...you changed your question so my answer no longer makes sense.  You can select the column names from syscolumns (select name from syscolumns 
where id in (select id from sysobjects where name = 'table1')) and use those results to build a sql statement in a variable.  It's a pain and can be hard to troubleshoot.  I hate to say it...If SQL is a high powered car, using a cursor is getting out and pushing.  I guess you can, but why would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the above desired, I have developed an API for Pro*C, which has several functions and inbuilt classes to make `DB` interaction using `Pro*C` really easy. See [CODBC](http://www.codbc.com).

Sample Code:

```
 int main()
 {
      SQLHelper DB("username","password");
      vector< vector<string> > rowData;
      try
      {
           DB.openDB(); //connect to oracle database
           if(DB.checkDBStatus())  //if connected to database or not
           {
                cout<<"connected"<<endl;
           }
           rowData=DB.selectDB("select to_char(sysdate) from dual"); //fetch all rows in rowData
           if(rowData.size()>0) //to check if rows are fetched or not
           {
                for(int i=0;i<rowData.size();i++) //access each row
                {
                     for(int j=0;j<rowData.at(i).size();j++) //access each column
                     {
                          cout<<rowData.at(i).at(j);
                     }
                     cout<<endl;
                }
           }
           else
           {
                cout<<"No rows fetched"<<endl;
           }
      }
      catch(SQLHelperException sqlExp) //catch any exception during SQL execution
      {
           cout<<sqlExp.getExceptionString()<<endl;
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

This is how we can retrieve any table without knowing it description.